# The workflow of VASP

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, software-assistance

I am trying to understand the workflow of VASP, so I make a simple diagram to show how VASP updates the related file during iteration. Did I make it right?

[image]

Comment: Are you just interested in the files? I wouldn't have thought it would do so much file I/O per SCF iteration. I'm not a VASP expert, but the contents of the files looks about right.

Comment: It would help future searchability of the question if you summarize the flowchart using a numbered list/bullet points in the text of the post. This will also make it easier for users to answer the question (not a real example: "point 5 is correct, but you have misunderstood point 3").

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.